# GET request Output - Unable to format to JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Here is my code.

```
import requests
import json
url ="https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/CMS/queue/213/issue"
auth='<USERNAME>', '<PASSWORD>'
r = requests.get(url, auth=(auth))
data = r.json()
print(data)
```

Here is the result of it.

```
{'size': 4, 'start': 0, 'limit': 50, 'isLastPage': True, '_links': {'self': 'https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/5/queue/213/issue', 'base': 'https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net', 'context': ''}, 'values': [{'id': '65615', 'self': 'https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/65615', 'key': 'CMS-5900', 'fields': {'summary': 'Void Refunded Clients', 'customfield_10700': [{'id': '4', 'name': 'BBOXX Capital DRC', '_links': {'self': 'https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/organization/4'}}], 'customfield_10800': {'_links': {'jiraRest': 'https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/65615', 'web': 'https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/5/CMS-5900', 'self': 'https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request/65615'}, 'requestType': {'_expands': ['field'], 'id': '145', '_links': {'self': 'https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/5/requesttype/145'}, 'name': 'CRM', 'description': '', 'helpText': '', 'issueTypeId': '10400', 'serviceDeskId': '5', 'groupIds': ['32'], 'icon': {'id': '13612', '_links': {'iconUrls': {'48x48': 'https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?avatarType=SD_REQTYPE&avatarId=1
```

Actual Output:

[image: Actual Output]

The Output that I want is to be something like this. I've searched on google and read in here but unfortunately, still, I can't get the output that I want.

```
{
    "size": 4,
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 50,
    "isLastPage": true,
    "_links": {
        "self": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/5/queue/213/issue",
        "base": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net",
        "context": ""
    },
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "65615",
            "self": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/65615",
            "key": "CMS-5900",
            "fields": {
                "summary": "Void Refunded Clients",
                "customfield_10700": [
                    {
                        "id": "4",
                        "name": "BBOXX Capital DRC",
                        "_links": {
                            "self": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/organization/4"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "customfield_10800": {
                    "_links": {
```

Comment: [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) seems like it will do what you want. Please don't post credentials online...

Comment: you can use `print( json.dumps(data, indent=4) )` to convert data to string with 4 spaces indentions.

Comment: Thank you @furas That solve's my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As furas explains,
you can use `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))`
to convert data to string with 4 spaces indentions,
which matches your example output.